# What's Wrong With this Derivative Approximation?

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, computational-mathematics

The following problem was given in my math book:

[image]

I can't see what's wrong with the analysis for the life of me. I suspect it has something to do with $f'''(\xi_1)-f'''(\xi_2)$ being greater than or equal to h, perhaps? But I just cannot wrap my head around what could be wrong here. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What are the assumptions on $f$?

Comment: @podiki there are no assumptions. This is the entire problem.

Comment: What if the function isn't differentiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the analysis is wrong, it's just that it gives an unnecessarily bad result. What happens if you go one step further in the expansions before adding them up? (Of course under the assumption that $f$ is nice enough to allow this.)

Comment: Ooooh, this totally makes sense, thanks! It kinda feels like the question in the book was poorly phrased in that case.